# Error building Spring-boot from Master - Tests Failed: Timeout on blocking read for 30000 MILLISECONDS

Tags: spring-boot

It's my first time trying to contribute in opensource. I'm trying to build Spring-Boot from Master without any change using the following command:

```
./mvnw -Pfull -X clean install
```

And all the test from class JettyReactiveWebServerFactoryTests failed with the following error:

```
[ERROR] noCompressionForUserAgent(org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.jetty.JettyReactiveWebServerFactoryTests)  
Time elapsed: 30.021 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Timeout on blocking read for 30000 MILLISECONDS
```

I could build without any problems the 1.5.X branch, but 2.0.X or greater failed with the same error.

I already changed the MAVEN_OPTS in my .bash_profile in order to increase the amount of memory available to Maven.

I'm using macOS High Sierra and JDK 8.0.181-oracle

Do I need to configure something else? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which is Jdk version that you are using?

Comment: I'm using the version: 8.0.181-oracle

Comment: Looks like your version of Jetty reactive is not on version of spring boot 2.x.x

Comment: Can you try `./mvnw clean install` for a start. No need to change your `MAVEN_OPTS` for now.

Comment: Thanks @StephaneNicoll! I got the same error without chaning `MAVEN_OPTS` and trying that command